# Cant boot into Win7 anymore - RebuildBCD wont work - Startup repair wont recognize windows drive

Tags: windows-7, boot, partitioning, repair, bcd

When I try booting into my windows 7, there is a black screen saying that \Boot\BCD is missing or corrupt.

What I did was get a Windows 7 iso onto a USB and when I boot that, the "Load Drives" cant find a windows 7 installation for some reason. I did a lot of searching and found myself doing the bootrec commands to see if that would fix my issue. All the commands work minus `bootrec /RebuildBCD`. It sees that windows is on my E:/ drive but when I press yes it states `The system cannot find the path specified`.

When I try going into the boot folder using `cd boot` it cant find the file so I assume its deleted?

Another thing I noticed is when using diskpart my E drive does have a 100mb partition which may be my boot partition that it is not using so that might lead to something to allow this to work correctly...

The last thing I read up is to use EasyBCD but I guess I would need a working Windows (my laptop) and some way to take my SSD and have an adapter to USB so that I can fix it on my laptop that way...

Comment: Is the issue that you can't boot your Windows 7 ISO from a USB?  If that is the issue, I'd assume you need to use a program such as Rufus to unpack the ISO so the files are recognized by your system.

Comment: Win7 on ISO USB boots fine (its not installed just used to get me to the "repair" functions), my E:/ drive with Win7 on it has the issue

Comment: Did you type `E:` <enter> then `cd boot` <enter>?  Or you just ran it from `X:`? See [Use Bootrec.exe in the Windows RE to troubleshoot startup issues](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/927392/use-bootrec-exe-in-the-windows-re-to-troubleshoot-startup-issues)

Comment: Yes I ran everything under ```E:``` and did ```cd boot``` and it had no file there. Ran all of the ```bootrec``` commands there too

Answer (score 0):

First action is to backup any files for which you don't have backups, 
using a Linux live boot media.

In the hope that your disk has not encountered any hardware errors,
one solution would be to do Startup Repair.

On Windows 7 you could access it from the Windows Error Recovery screen
by choosing  "Launch Startup repair (Recommended)".

If you don't get this screen, then press <kbd>F8</kbd> as Windows boots
to enter the Advanced Boot Options screen, where you may
select "Repair Your Computer".

If even this does not work, you may boot from a Windows 7 boot media of same
service pack level and use the Repair option.
A system repair disc/drive can also work, if you have created one.

If nothing works, you should seriously consider the possibility that the disk
itself has a problem. Reinstalling Windows is the best option.
Be sure to do a slow (not quick) format of the
disk during the installation, as this finds and marks disk errors.
If too many errors are found, then the disk is done for.

Comment: My files are all backed up, just want to make this win7 work for me. F8 key does not work for me as it is my BIOS boot options. I tried F12 and it just gives me a blank screen with a blinking cursor. Also the win7 USB when I do repair it cant find the windows drive for some reason... even though bootrec can find it on E:/ drive. The disk itself has no issues because its a new 850 that I cloned to have the exact same files as my original windows installation (because i didnt want to touch the existing one incase of corrupting other files and to successfully do backups)

Comment: Has the new disk ever booted up, meaning it is the first boot with it, or did it work but suddenly this happened now? Was the old disk an SSD? What model exactly is the new disk?

Comment: The original SSD that had windows 7 that originally got corrupted was not visible on diskpart or anything so what I did was clone that drive onto another drive that used to have the same win7 on it long time ago that I used just to store old data. From samsung 960 to 850. Im almost 100% sure the drive I cloned to works.

Comment: Do you mean that you cloned a disk that was already corrupted?

Comment: Yes because the original disk that was already corrupted was not visible at all so I had to move everything over to a drive that was visible to do any work on it. I know its corrupted but I couldnt change or see it anywhere and could only see my E drive. Now my E drive is identical to the C drive but E is visible and C is not.

Comment: So now I am trying to get E drive to work then once everything works and I can boot into 7, I am going to work on upgrading the E drive to win10 afterward and clone it back to C

Comment: If the Windows partition is not recognized as such by the boot media, this means that it is in a really bad shape. Highly likely that cloning duplicated the corruption. Sometimes the fix is to install Windows from scratch on the new disk, then copy over the files from the old Windows partition. Success will depend on the extent of the corruption.